# SSO authentication integration issue

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, authentication, single-sign-on

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5. I need to implement SSO (Single Sign On feature) with another site. The SSO protocol is like this,

1. The other site will send me information like http://mysitename/default.aspx?Identity=abc or like http://mysitename/default.aspx (mysitename is the site which I am developing);
2. If the value Identity variable is null, it means anonymous user. And if the Identity value is not null (means an authenticated user), I will using a WCF interface to find user information (e.g. user name and email address) from the Identity variable;
3. The actual user name, user profile (e.g. email address) and password are maintained by the other site;
4. My site will manage roles by myself (i.e. the other site and my site only shares user credential authentication function to implement SSO, role management are performed individually in two sites).

Any ideas how to integrate such SSO feature?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you state whether your SharePoint site is using Windows or Forms authentication, I assume the source website is using Forms right?

Comment: Yes, using Forms authentication in the past. Any ideas?

Comment: @George2: Do you have an update for this question or more information for CJG?

Answer (score 1):

Basically your saying you want people to access your site as an identity, but use another person's user store for the auth.

This is claims based auth my friend.  The other end would need to support an interface where they login to there site and redirect you to yours.  You would then need to do a mapping to a user in your site to the user in their site.  You could do this if they send claims (ie the username, email, whatever).

You could add an site page to your site where they can post the data (ie claims), do the lookup, and then just use basic forms based auth calls to do the login on your site as your user.

did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you are using the SSO functionality that ships with MOSS then you are out of luck. The default SSO provider ONLY works with AD authenticated users. You can roll your own SSO provider if you want it to work with FBA users but that doesn't solve the problem of automatically logging the user into SharePoint.

You can create an HttpModule that can log users in. I have seen examples on the web of this but I have not done it myself.